# Power BI Visualization ID instead of Xpath

Tags: powerbi, ui-automation

One of my team's QA testers has requested if there was a way to create a unique id for visualizations/elements in Power BI reports so it would be easier to identify the component with his automated UI test scripts.

He's pulling the various elements out with xpaths that are tedious.

Making life easier for our testers - it's the right thing to do.

Is there a way I could create unique ids for the various elements I use in a Power BI report that would make it easier to identify the elements with UI test scripts?

I've been searching and either I'm using the wrong search terms or it's not a thing.

Comment: Are your testers testing the data or the actual visualization output?  Your test approach could be a bit different if the goal it to test data vs Visualizations.

Comment: He's testing the visualizations output based on automated input data. Although, I'm not testing the reports. I'm just creating reports that I'd like to identify visualizations/elements so they are easier to test.
Do you know how to create ids within Power BI for the different elements?

Comment: Don't think that is possible.  That is internal to Power BI and how it renders the data.

Comment: Thanks.
It looks like folks have requested this ability, but it's low priority and probably not going to be implemented any time soon.